# Percentage Validation in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have tax percentage field .In that i want to validate for numeric ,tax percentage not greater than 100% , decimal places only 2.
 my demo code is

```
$result = $this->validate['TaxPercent'] = array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule'    => 'numeric',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __("err__numberfield", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
            ),
            'range' => array(
                'rule' => array('range', 0, 101),
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __("err__percentage", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
            ),
            'decimal' => array(
                'rule' => array('decimal', 2),
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __("err__decimal", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
            )
        );
```

please suggest appropriate solution.

Comment: What is the type of your database field?

Comment: please reply immediately.

Comment: Your validation rules won't accept "0.00%" and will accept "100.99%" - since you're probably aware _something_ is wrong with the code in the question - state what you know to avoid readers who aren't familiar wasting their time guessing what's wrong. And in-keeping with your last comment: Please edit the question immediately. Urgent.

Comment: okey sir, so please send me updated code for accept numeric + decimal(12,2)+range.